# WCF pass XML document

Tags: c#, wcf

I created WCF Services. I have two files:

**IHelloService.cs file:**

```
namespace HelloService
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloService
    {            
        [OperationContract]
        void GetXmlDocumentt(XmlDocument Doc);
    }
}
```

---

**HelloService.cs file:**

```
public void GetXmlDocumentt(XmlDocument Doc)
{
   // return Doc;
}
```

I chose "Add Service Reference" and add my service reference and type in my client application:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
//.. load xml from file

HelloService.HelloServiceClient client = new HelloService.HelloServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IHelloService");

client.GetXmlDocumentt(xmlDoc); // I get error in this line
```

I don't know why? because when I repleace type from XmlDocument to string in interface and I will pass `client.GetXmlDocumentt("any data")` string in this line, everything works good.

Can you explain me why string type works but `XmlDocument` don't work?

How can I change the code to `XmlDocument`  work good?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if we knew what the error message said rather than just "it doesn't work / it errors" etc.

Comment: error messages:The best overloaded method match for 'MvcLogowanie.HelloService.HelloServiceClient.GetXmlDocumentt(object[])' has some invalid arguments
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' to 'object[]'

Answer (score 2):

`XmlDocument` doesn't implement `IXmlSerializable` interface, which is used by DataContractSerializer. You have 3 ways:

1. Use `Xml.Linq` to deal with xml and send your data in `XDocument` class.
2. Send your xml as string and validate it on client side.
3. You can serialize your document to bytes stream and then deserialize it on client side.